# what should I do if i've find a larger prime number than the largest

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

I've found a prime number larger than the known largest prime number; it has 21,785,121 digits.

Who should I contact for the award (if there is one)?

Thanks.

Comment: some one else will find another even bigger

Comment: Can you prove it's prime?

Comment: https://www.eff.org/press/archives/2009/10/14-0 - you're a bit short for the next EFF awards (100 million and 1 billion digits)

Comment: As a hypothetical, still a good question.

Comment: What an interesting question you asked? :)

Comment: the largest known prime number has 17,425,170 digits : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number i have 21,785,121

Comment: You could email the people of GIMPS, the creators of RSA, or any another related group to ask this.

Comment: There is no Mersenne prime with this number of digits.

Comment: Avi Steiner, sorry, but the largest known prime number is more than 24 million digits long, so you probably won't get anything for it. But still, it's a huge accomplishment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.eff.org/awards/coop) is a list of the rewards still offered by the EFF for the discovery of a sufficiently large prime.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that your discovery meets their criteria. I am not aware of any similar awards being offered.

If that's a Mersenne prime you have, you may want to contact the folks over at [GIMPS](http://www.mersenne.org/prime.htm).

Comment: It's quite odd that if he found a prime of this size, yet he would not have heard of EFF. A [Google search](https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=cr&ei=LlLAUviBEYrXygGbuIGADQ#q=largest+prime+award) for "largest prime award" yields it as the 2nd result. If there's an announcement soon for a 21-million-digit prime, we'll know its him. If there's none, well...

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a provable prime, you should submit the prime to [Caldwell's *The Prime Pages* site](https://primes.utm.edu/bios/submission.php). The same is true for any prime that makes it into the [Top 5000](https://primes.utm.edu/primes/download.php) of largest currently known primes.

The Top 5000 does not have your prime with 21,785,121 digits. It would be 4th in the list (as of today), and also the largest known non-Mersenne prime. (There is no Mersenne exponent in the interval $[72368602.1, 72368605.5]$; J.R.'s comment to the question.)

If it is nothing more than a **probable prime**, it is still interesting given its size. You should submit it to [Lifchitz & Lifchitz's *PRP Top* site](http://www.primenumbers.net/prptop/) where it would easily be number one (they do not accept provable primes).